# XML parsing in java with JDOM(getChildren method returns no List)

Tags: java, xml, jdom

For an xml file which its  root has 25 children, getChildren method return list.size= 0 !!

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
       File xmlFile = new File("g:\\*");
        try {

    Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
    Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
    List list = rootNode.getChildren("job",Namespace.getNamespace("Montage"));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
                {

       Element node = (Element) list.get(i);
               System.out.println("ID : " + node.getAttributeValue("id"));
       System.out.println("Run Time : " + node.getAttributeValue("runtime"));
            }
        }
             catch (IOException io) {
    System.out.println(io.getMessage());
  } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
    System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
  }

    }
```

Here the portion of xml file:

```
<adag xmlns="http://pegasus.isi.edu/schema/DAX"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://pegasus.isi.edu/schema/DAX http://pegasus.isi.edu/schema/dax-2.1.xsd" version="2.1" count="1" index="0" name="test" jobCount="25" fileCount="0" childCount="20">
 <job id="ID00000" namespace="Montage" name="mProjectPP" version="1.0" runtime="13.39">
  <uses file="region.hdr" link="input" register="true" transfer="true" optional="false" type="data" size="304" /> 
  <uses file="2mass-atlas-ID00000s-jID00000.fits" link="input" register="true" transfer="true" optional="false" type="data" size="4222080" /> 
  <uses file="p2mass-atlas-ID00000s-jID00000.fits" link="output" register="true" transfer="true" optional="false" type="data" size="4167312" /> 
  <uses file="p2mass-atlas-ID00000s-jID00000_area.fits" link="output" register="true" transfer="true" optional="false" type="data" size="4167312" /> 
  </job>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `job` element has an attribute named `namespace`, whose value is "Montage", but that doesn't make the job element part of the "Montage" namespace.

Just use

```
List list = rootNode.getChildren("job");
```

Comment: Actually the namespace of the "job" elements is `http://pegasus.isi.edu/schema/DAX`

Comment: Need to add these code:Namespace ns=rootNode.getNamespace();
  List list = rootNode.getChildren("job",ns);